# What does this error message " Unexpected do block in function application" mean?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to compile this function but I get an error. What is it that Haskell is not happy about?

```
copyFile :: FilePath ->  FilePath -> IO()
copyFile fromFile toFile = 
     do c <- readFile fromFile
    writeFile toFile c
```

Unexpected do block in function application:
        do c <- readFile fromFile
    You could write it with parentheses
    Or perhaps you meant to enable BlockArguments?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The indentation is not entirely correct, and as a result the compiler parses this as if the `do` is only applied to the `c <- readFile fromFile`, and not to the `writeFile`.

```
copyFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO()
copyFile fromFile toFile = do
    c <- readFile fromFile
    writeFile toFile c
```

or shorter:

```
copyFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO()
copyFile fromFile toFile = readFile fromFile >>= writeFile toFile
```

That being said, I strongly recommend to use [**`copyFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.4.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:copyFile) or [**`copyFileWithMetadata :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.4.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:copyFileWithMetadata) instead. That way you do not load the content of the file in memory (the file might be larger than the amount of available memory). Some file systems could improve the efficiency significantly, for example by only adding an extra reference to the file, and making a real copy in case one of the two files is modified.